# How to suppress a warning message

Tags: warning-messages, version-10, precision-and-accuracy

If I change `$MinPrecision` before running `ListPlot[{{1, 2}}]`, there will be a warning in *Mathematica* 10. But there is no warning in *Mathematica* 9. Is there a way to avoid this warning?

```
$MinPrecision = 30;
ListPlot[{{1, 2}}]
```

> N::precsm: "Requested precision 16 is smaller than \$MinPrecision. Using \$MinPrecision instead."

Added: What I wanted to ask is not how to suppress a warning message in general. In fact, I think it is unreasonable for *Mathematica* 10 to have this warning, because (1) *Mathematica* 9 does not have it; (2) it is not useful. `Off[N::"precsm"]` does solve the problem, but some useful warnings may also be suppressed as well.

Comment: For a single instance you can use `Quiet`.  To suppress the message globally you can use `Off[N::"precsm"]`.  If that solves your problem this should probably be closed.  If it does not please edit your question to explain why.

Comment: This seems to be a change in `ListPlot`, perhaps to accurately convert exact data to approximate real data.  I would suggest that you report it to Wolfram Research.  Probably the internal code should read `N[data, Max[16, $MinPrecision]]` instead of something like `N[data, 16]`.

Answer (score 6):

It is best to do this sort of thing within a [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html), so `$MinPrecision` is not changed globally, but only inside the scope of `Block`.

I recommend

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 30}, Off[N::precsm]; ListPlot[{{1, 2}}]]
```

but

```
Block[{$MinPrecision = 30}, Quiet @ ListPlot[{{1, 2}}]]
```

will work as well.